# Angular 7, p-table PrimeNG: Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'SlicePipe'

Tags: html, angular

Estou tentando fazer uma listagem em uma "p-table" do primeng, até ontem estava listando tudo perfeitamente, mas hoje ao rodar o projeto angular notei que estava ocorrendo este erro. Não faço a menor idéia do que significa e muito menos o motivo, pois tudo estava funcionando normalmente.

**Erro:**

```
TableBody.html:8 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'SlicePipe'
at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4323)
at SlicePipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.SlicePipe.transform (common.js:5812)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TableBody.html:8)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23511)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23308)
at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
```

**Linha 8 do TableBody.html: (onde ocorre o erro. obs: nunca entrei nesse arquivo)**

```
<ng-template ngFor let-rowData let-rowIndex="index" [ngForOf]="(dt.paginator && !dt.lazy) ? ((dt.filteredValue||dt.value) | slice:dt.first:(dt.first + dt.rows)) : (dt.filteredValue||dt.value)" [ngForTrackBy]="dt.rowTrackBy">
```

**O codigo da minha tabela.html e do componente.ts: (obs: o método GET está funcionando normalmente retornando todos os dados, já testei separadamente e o problema ocorre quando cai os dados na tabela.)**
[Código disponível no codeshare](https://codeshare.io/duvidaptable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passei pelo mesmo problema com Angular 7 e PrimeNG.

No meu caso, estava recebendo um objeto Observable contendo dentro dele um array com os dados da requisição GET no back-end.

Para iterar na tabela do PrimeNG você precisa de um Array.

Dessa forma, foi preciso buscar dentro do objeto o array com os dados e armazenar na variável dentro do componente.

```js
//função get dentro do service.ts
return this.http
           .get<any[]>(`${this.url}`)
           .pipe(
                 map(res => res['content']) //pegando o array no HttpResponse
           );
```

Depois, no componente, armazena o array na variável e itera sobre ela para exibir.